# Simple cURL script doesn't retrieve data

Tags: php, curl

I'm just starting to learn cURL and now I simply try all kind of things to get used to the options that cURL give me.Here is a simple script which I use to connect and retrieve data from a current site

```
<?php

      $ch=curl_init();
      $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
      $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
      $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
      $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
      $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
      $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://img2.somesite.net/bitbucket/");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $a=curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      echo $a;

?>
```

I want to get the images stored there, but obviously I miss something.I'm not sure how it should be done.When you write `http://img2.somesite.net/bitbucket/pic.jpg` the image is loaded.I want to get the name of all files that are there, or maybe I should trigger a command which will download the images and then check them on the PC...I don't know is this possible with cURL and hwo could be done?
  Also when I leave it

```
http://somesite.net/
```

I get the resource back, so basicly this works...

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Ops, I want to do it via cURL

Comment: Well, just for the sake of it i tried and : `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in C:\Program Files...`

Comment: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in C:\Program Files` - this

Comment: does the page you are requesting exists?

Comment: yes, when I use the script below and leave http://somesite.net/ it works, but it's mentioned in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a User-Agent, as Some sites block requests without a user agent.

Also, download Tamper Data for firefox and see the Headers being sent to the Server when you initiate the download from your browser. Imitiate all the Headers from curl and that will do it.

Thats how i do it.

Comment: Nice, still way from making an workin cURL script but hope this program will help

Comment: If you would give the actual URL then maybe we can help more, but without that, Tamper Data is all i can think of for you.

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_HEADER is a boolean value determining whether it should return the requests' headers.
To pass headers to cURL, you should use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

This should work just fine:

```
<?php
      $ch=curl_init();
      $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
      $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
      $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
      $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
      $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
      $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://img2.somesite.net/bitbucket/");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $a=curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: That exact code returns 404 - Not Found, as my riginal one, maybe I really should be more specific about the browser headers.